# Laravel display collection items in view

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using a package called cybercog/laravel-love. This package includes a method that returns a collection of users who liked model

`$sheet->collectLikers()`

When I add this to my view it returns a collection of users just fine but how do I get just the users username for example.

`[{"id":1,"first_name":null,"last_name":null,"email":"mem1@email.com","username":"mem1","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2018-10-15 16:45:14","updated_at":"2018-10-15 16:45:14"},{"id":2,"first_name":null,"last_name":null,"email":"mem2@email.com","username":"mem2","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2018-10-15 16:45:14","updated_at":"2018-10-15 16:45:14"}]`

`{{ $sheet->collectLikers()->username }}` returns nothing as does
`{{ $sheet->collectLikers('username') }}`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this... pretty easy actually. Needed to loop through.

`@foreach($sheet->collectLikers() as $userLike)
    {{ $userLike->username }}
 @endforeach`